# Translating Python loop to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

How can I yield the same output in Javascript, given this Python example?

I want to loop over an array and check a value, if condition met, store it.

```
arr1 = [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
        13, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0,
         0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,
         0,  0]

new_labels = []
previous = None
for l in arr1:
    if l != previous:
        new_labels.append(l)
        previous = l

# expected: 
[0, 7, 0, 13, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 14, 0, 2, 0]
```

Comment: please make an attempt before asking (and share [mcve])

Comment: If you ask https://chat.openai.com/chat you'll get your answer in like 2 seconds by saying "Convert this python code to javascript" and then pasting your python code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done more simply with [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```js
let arr1 = [ 0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  7,  7,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,13, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 13, 13,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,0,  0,  0, 15,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0, 14,  0,  0,0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  2,  0,0,  0];
let res = arr1.filter((x, i) => x !== arr1[i - 1]);
console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Comment: Would fail if the value at index 0 happened to be undefined, but I suppose that's not going to happen here.